# How can i reduce rename time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ubuntu, sed

So, i have ~ 6k files, what i need to check and if need, rename.
The why is, i some image name i have accent character what i dont' need, and need to rename to simple character.
Eg.:

Bas-v-s-Broek-DTR-025-Dobszék-állítható-magasságú.jpg

to

Bas-v-s-Broek-DTR-025-Dobszek-allithato-magassagu.jpg

I'm doing now this work with find and rename:

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/ ö|ő|ó|ö/o/g' '{}' \; -exec rename 's/ ü|ű|ú/u/g' '{}' \; -exec rename 's/ á/a/g' '{}' \; -exec rename 's/ é/e/g' '{}' \; -exec rename 's/ í/i/g' '{}' \;
```

and the problem is now take longer than 30-35 min. Can i reduce somehow this process time? I need to check recursivly, all sub-folders.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i finded the perfect solution.
The find have regex option(what i don't know), and now much faster!
Egg, how i use:

```
find . -regex '.*[á].*' -type f -exec rename 's/á/a/g' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should aim to reduce the number of invocations of `rename`, since fork+execve are relatively expensive operations.

You can do this by joining all the patterns into a single `rename` command, and then have `find` execute it on multiple files at a time with `+` instead of `\;`:

```
find . -type f -exec \
   rename 's/ö|ő|ó|ö/o/g; s/ü|ű|ú/u/g; s/á/a/g; s/é/e/g; s/í/i/g' '{}' +
```

Comment: (Well, a single command per however many filenames fit on a command line)